# How can I get my notification to be compact in Android Oreo?

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

I've got my notifications to work well on my app with API range being 21-26. I spent two hours looking this up and I couldn't really find a solution. I could've been searching the wrong thing but this is what I'm looking for:

[Compact Notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4L213.png)

Here is my notification manager code:

```
    @TargetApi(26)
private void runNotificationManager() {
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = 
(NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    id = "auto_birthday_01";
    CharSequence name = getString(R.string.channel_name);
    String description = getString(R.string.channel_description);
    int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN;
    NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(id, name, importance);
    mChannel.setDescription(description);
    mChannel.enableVibration(false);
    mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);

}
```

Here is my notification code:

```
  private void runNotification(NotificationManager notificationManager) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, id);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
    0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    builder.setLargeIcon(
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round));
    builder.setContentTitle("Title!");
    builder.setContentText("Open.");
    builder.setOngoing(true);
    notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
}
```

All I get is the standard notification all the way on top. Thank you.